# To find the last value in the dataset of 15 minutes interval

Tags: hana

```
   ID Timestamp Value                                                               
   -- --------- -----
   1   11:59.54   10
   1   12.04.00   20
   1   12.12.00   31
   1   12.16.00   10
   1   12.48.00   05
```

I want the result set as

```
   ID Timestamp Value
   -- --------- -----
   1   11:59.54   10
   1   12:00:00   10
   1   12.04.00   20
   1   12.12.00   31
   1   12:15:00   31
   1   12:16.00   10
   1   12:30:00   10
   1   12:45:00   10
   1   12.48.00   05
```

Comment: then do it. Seriously... try something out and when you run into errors or problems you can't fix, ask. SO is not meant for "requirements in -> code out".

Comment: Dear Calon, 
have tried to by best knowledge and was unable to generate this data set, as a last resort I have posted over here.

Comment: Can you handle missing results at the application level?

Comment: Why are all the ids '1'? Why do they appear *at all* in the result set?!?

Comment: @Strawberry Its like data from one module, at that intervals.

Comment: "Id" typically implies a surrogate PRIMARY KEY, so it's a little confusing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea is as follows. Use [`SERIES_GENERATE()`](https://help.sap.com/viewer/4fe29514fd584807ac9f2a04f6754767/2.0.00/en-US/c8101037ad4344768db31e68e4d30eb4.html) to generate the missing time stamps with the 15 minute intervals and and union it with the existing data your table `T`. Now you would want to use `LAST_VALUE` with `IGNORE NULLS`. `IGNORE NULLS` is not implemented in HANA, therefore you have to do a bit of a workaround. I use `COUNT()` as a [window function](https://help.sap.com/viewer/4fe29514fd584807ac9f2a04f6754767/2.0.00/en-US/20a353327519101495dfd0a87060a0d3.html) to count the non null values. I do the same on the original data and then join both on the count. This way I repeat the last non-null value.

```
select X.ID, X.TIME, Y.VALUE from (
    select ID, TIME, value, 
        count(VALUE) over (order by TIME rows between unbounded preceding and current row) as CNT 
    from (
        --add the missing 15 minute interval timestamps
        select 1 as ID, GENERATED_PERIOD_START as TIME, NULL as VALUE 
        from SERIES_GENERATE_TIME('INTERVAL 15 MINUTE', '12:00:00', '13:00:00')
        union all 
        select ID, TIME, VALUE from T
    )
) as X join (
    select ID, TIME, value, 
           count(value) over (order by TIME rows between unbounded preceding and current row) as CNT
    from T
) as Y on X.CNT = Y.CNT
```

Answer (score 3):

More coffee will probably lead to a simpler solution, but consider the the following...

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
,timestamp TIMESTAMP
,value INT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
(1   ,'11:59:54',10),
(2   ,'12:04:00',20),
(3   ,'12:12:00',31),
(4   ,'12:16:00',10),
(5   ,'12:48:00',05);
```

... in addition, I have a table of integers, that looks like this:

```
SELECT * FROM ints;
+---+
| i |
+---+
| 0 |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |
| 4 |
| 5 |
| 6 |
| 7 |
| 8 |
| 9 |
+---+
```

So...

```
SELECT a.timestamp
     , b.value
  FROM 
     ( SELECT x.*
            , MIN(y.timestamp) min_timestamp
         FROM 
            ( SELECT timestamp
                FROM my_table
               UNION
              SELECT SEC_TO_TIME((i2.i*10+i1.i)*900)
                FROM ints i1
                   , ints i2 
               WHERE SEC_TO_TIME((i2.i*10+i1.i)*900) 
                     BETWEEN (SELECT MIN(timestamp) FROM my_table) 
                         AND (SELECT MAX(timestamp) FROM my_table) 
               ORDER 
                  BY timestamp
            ) x
         LEFT
         JOIN my_table y
           ON y.timestamp >= x.timestamp
        GROUP 
           BY x.timestamp
    ) a
 JOIN my_table b
   ON b.timestamp = min_timestamp;

+-----------+-------+
| timestamp | value |
+-----------+-------+
| 11:59:54  |    10 |
| 12:00:00  |    20 |
| 12:04:00  |    20 |
| 12:12:00  |    31 |
| 12:15:00  |    10 |
| 12:16:00  |    10 |
| 12:30:00  |     5 |
| 12:45:00  |     5 |
| 12:48:00  |     5 |
+-----------+-------+
```